# Java generics in inheritence

Tags: java, generics

I am having some (philosophical?) problems with java's generics...

Consider the following

```
public interface ClassA<I> {}

public class Obj implements ClassA<String> {}    

public interface ClassB<I, T extends ClassA<I>> {
    public I getSomething();
    public T getAnotherThing();
}
```

This compiles and works ok, if an object of ClassB  is instantiated as:

```
ClassB<String, Obj<String>> o = new ClassB<>();
o.getSomething(); // <-- Returns String
```

I was wondering if there is a way to avoid instantiating a ClassB object without having to specify the String generic as well, since it's already inside ClassA. More specifically, I'd like to use it as:

```
public interface ClassB<T extends ClassA<I>> { // <-- Won't compile
    public I getSomething(); 
}
ClassB<Obj> o = new ClassB<>(); 
o.getSomething(); // <-- Returns String from Obj declaration, which uses ClassA<String>
```

I know the "problem" can be easily gotten over with the first example, but I wanted to know if there's a way of reference the actual type of the generic in the implementing ClassA object without having to pass it again in ClassB's declaration, and if not, why.

Hope I was clear enough with my dilemma. 
Thanks

Comment: The example is too trivial. If type `T` is never used or returned in `ClassB`, then just don't put it in the class declaration.

Comment: consider there are methods which expressly use methods in that class T (in this case, Obj). I didn't want to make the example to complex, as it would have taken focus off the actual question.

Comment: no, you can't do it. If you want to declare the method as returning a type you have to give that type a name

Comment: The only methods you can "expressly use in that class T" are ones from the bounds, i.e. from `ClassA<I>`. You simply don't need `T` in the class declaration.

Comment: please consider that T is simply necessary there. I'd complicate way too much the example if I put in code that expressly uses the generic T.

Comment: Just add a `public T getAnotherThing();` and then you have code that expressly uses the generic `T`. Is that really so much? :)

Comment: davmac, the question, as mentioned, is of _philosophical_ nature, and I'd say it is too much because it potentially violates Law of Demeter :)

Comment: @davmac: Very well. Added. I was building something a bit more complex in my mind, but your input is good.

Comment: @MichalM given that an example is provided, it doesn't seem too much to ask that the example actually reflects the problem in this _philosophical_ question, does it?

Comment: @dhke I think you've misread the question - it's `T extends ClassA<?>` where `ClassA` != `Class`.

Comment: @davmac Nah, yes. Scratch that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is "No". :)

Java doesn't provide a way to extract a type argument from a type itself, only from an argument having that type.

Eg:

```
class ClassB<T extends ClassA<?>> {
    <I> I getSomething(ClassA<I>) { ... }
}
```

... works fine and could be passed an instance of `T` in order to extract `I`. But to remove the parameter from the method (which is used only to determine the type for `I`) you'd need a way to determine I from T itself, and there is no such way.

In general, type inference in Java is limited to establishing a relationship between parameter types and/or between parameter and return types.

The other way, then, would be to declare `I` and `T` together as part of one generic parameter, as you tried:

```
public interface ClassB<T extends ClassA<I>>
```

But then, as you noted, this is not accepted either. Java's syntax would need to be expanded in order to allow this.